# Modifying an inherited member variable does not affect base class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, stdbind

I have the following two classes:

```
class A
{
public:

    A() : value(false) {}

    bool get() const
    {
        return value;
    }

protected:
    bool value;
};

class B : public A
{
public:

    void set()
    {
        value = true;
    }
};
```

Now I use them as follows:

```
B* b = new B;
std::shared_ptr<A> a(b);

auto func = std::bind(&B::set, *b);

std::cout << a->get() << std::endl;
func();
std::cout << a->get() << std::endl;
```

I expect `a->get()` to return `true` on the 2nd call, but `func()` hasn't modified its value. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::bind` takes its paramters by value, so you are operating on copy of `*b`.

You need to pass original object by `std::ref`:

```
auto func = std::bind(&B::set, std::ref(*b));
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/yfKaci)

Or simpler form would be just pass pointer to `bind`:

```
auto func = std::bind(&B::set, b);
```